# IoC Castle Windsor - No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm getting the 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object' on my controller when the controller and its dependencies are being registered accordingly via (DI/IoC) pattern using Castle Windsor.  Can someone take a look at the following and see my error because i can't see it.

[image]

Code for registration on global.asax

```
public class MyApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{ 
    public MvcApplication()
    {
        this.container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new DependencyInstaller());
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
        new WindsorActivator(this.container));
    }
}
```

My DI

```
public class DependencyInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IDatabaseFactory>().ImplementedBy<DatabaseFactory>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
            Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
            Component.For<IMappingEngine>().ImplementedBy<MappingEngine>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => Mapper.Engine).LifeStyle.Singleton,
            Component.For<IFirmTasks>().ImplementedBy<FirmTasks>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
            Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<PersonController>().BasedOn<IController>().LifestyleTransient(),
            Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IHttpController>().LifestyleTransient(),
            Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Core.Firm.Tasks").Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Tasks")).WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Core.Firm.Repository")
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).WithServiceAllInterfaces().LifestylePerWebRequest()
            );
    }
}
```

my controller

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private IFirmTasks tasks;

    public PersonController(IFirmTasks tasks)
    {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
```

When I load the application the container loads fine with all dependencies resolved as per screen shot on debug.

[image]

Anyone out there got any idea's where my failings lie.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When I load the application the container loads fine with all dependencies resolved as per screen shot on debug.

Yes, all your types are registered.

If you write `var controller = container.Resolve<PersonController>();` in the `Global.asax` you should get an instance of your controller.

**Your implementation is valid for Asp.Net WebApi and it works for `System.Web.Http.ApiController`s only.**

Your code does not work properly because your `PersonController` inherits `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` and `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory` is used. You can see it in the first picture.

**You should write and inject your custom ControllerFactory in `Global.asax` in order to create Asp.Net MVC controllers.**

```
    //Set the controller builder to use our custom controller factory
    var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container);
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

You can read [more in this answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338043/using-di-to-load-repository-instance-on-each-mvc-request/19339554#19339554).

Here is a default implementation of `WindsorControllerFactory`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Controller factory the class is to be used to eliminate hard-coded dependencies 
/// between controllers and other components
/// </summary>
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        container.Release(controller.GetType());
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```